VLC ignores configured soundfont
I'm using VLC 3.0.20 on Windows 10, and have configured a .sf2-soundfont in the Settings (Audiocodecs/FluidSynth). When I re-open the setting, the path pointing to the soundfont is still correct:

However, the error still persists:
MIDI-Synthese nicht eingerichtet:
Für die MIDI-Synthese wird eine Sound-Font-Datei (.SF2) benötigt.
Bitte Sound-Font installieren und über VLC-Einstellungen (Input / Codecs > Audiocodecs > FluidSynth) konfigurieren.

Codec wird nicht unterstützt:
VLC konnte das Format „MIDI“ (MIDI Audio) nicht dekodieren

(i.e. "MIDI synthesis not set up: for MIDI synthesis, a sound font file (.sf2) is needed").
What is the issue? Thanks in advance for any kind of help!

Could be the soundfont is inaccessible, e.g., it's in a user folder, but VLC and FluidSynth are being run as another user -- be sure the soundfont is accessible. It could be the soundfont is defective, or incomplete -- try another soundfont.

@DrMoishePippik Thanks for the comment. Running FluidSynth directly on the soundfont and midi produced a correct .wav, so I guess the soundfont should be ok. I tried running VLC as administrator, but it still didn't work. However, now I tried a different soundfont in a different folder and it worked.
